# Ext Panel Visible

Tags: c#, asp.net, extjs

I have a problem in Ext panel.(it is in server side(aspx page))

I have a two panel and this panel has buttons.(Buttons are dynamic(I am creating buttons in aspx.cs file))

I am visible second panel in page load and I want to open it first panel buttons click

Second panel is visible but when I click the button I can not show it. :(

I am using this code for panel's visible:

page load -> pnlRigh.Visible = false;

on button click -> pnlRigh.Visible = true;

How can I show panel when I click the button.

Thanks,

John